# Trying to implement perameters (arguments) (args[]) into static double

Tags: java, parsing, static, command-line-arguments, args

I'm kinda new to running parameters through the command line. I'm having trouble implementing the last 4 parameters to the command line so a sample input on the command line would be `java newton 2 4 .005 50 1 2 0 5` with the `1 2 0 5` being the coefficients of the polynomial in the static double at the bottom in the return catch.

It should read `1x^3 + 2x^2 + 0^2 + 5`. Everything seems to work but I can't get the args to stick to the bottom and don't know why. If anyone can help me please I've been up almost 10 hours trying to research and can't seem to find any help anywhere about this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class newton {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x0, xnew, xxnew;// Initiating double
        double x1, p1;
        double fx0, fx1;
        double delta, delta1; // amount added to get next iterate
        double error; // error estimate
        double tol = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);// tolerance (max error)
        int i, maxIts, j; // iteration count and maximum number of
                            // iteraterations made
        x0 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        x1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        p1 = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
        maxIts = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

        DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.############");

        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Polynomail Root Finder By [Gilbert Jimenez]" + "\n");
        System.out.println("Initial Perameters :" + "\n");
        System.out.println("P0 : = " + args[0]);
        System.out.println("p1 : = " + args[1]);
        System.out.println("Tol = " + tol);
        System.out.println("Maximum = " + maxIts + "\n");
        System.out.println("Polynomial is of order:  4 ");
        System.out.println("Terms of polynomial: " + args[4] + "x^3" + "+" + args[5] + "x^2" + "+" + args[6] + "x" + "+"
                + args[7]);

        {
            // Performing Newton's method
            i = 1;
            error = 100;
            System.out.println("Newtons Method:\t     " + "\n");

            while (i <= maxIts && error > tol) {
                delta = -(f(x0) / fprime(x0));
                error = Math.abs(delta);
                xnew = x0 + delta;

                System.out.println("p" + i + "\t" + fmt.format(xnew));
                i++;
                x0 = xnew;
            }

            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("Solution found after " + i + " " + "itterations :" + fmt.format(x0) + "\n");
        }

        {
            // Performing
            j = 1;
            error = 100;

            System.out.println("Secant Method:\t   " + "\n");
            fx0 = f(x0);
            while (j <= maxIts && error > tol) {
                fx1 = f(x1);
                delta1 = (-fx1 * (x1 - x0) / (fx1 - fx0));
                error = Math.abs(delta1);
                xxnew = x1 + delta1;

                System.out.println("p" + j + "\t" + fmt.format(xxnew));
                j++;
                x0 = x1;
                fx0 = fx1;
                x1 = xxnew;
            }

            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("Solution found after " + j + " " + "itterations :" + fmt.format(x1) + "\n");
        }
    }

    // function of f
    public static double f(double x) {
        return (x * x * x - 2.0 * x * x + 0 * x - 5);
    }

    // derivative of f
    public static double fprime(double x) {
        return (3.0 * x * x - 4.0 * x);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the polynomial takes the form: a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d

List of changes made:

- Changed the class name to Newton (from newton)
- Saved the polynomial co-efficients into a, b, c, d
- Modified functions f() and fprime() to use a, b, c, d

Please try and see if this helps.

```
   public class Newton {

        static int a = 0;
        static int b = 0;
        static int c = 0;
        static int d = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args)  {

            double x0, xnew, xxnew;// Initiating double
            double x1, p1;
            double fx0, fx1;
            double delta, delta1; // amount added to get next iterate
            double error; // error estimate
            double tol = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);// tolerance (max error)

            int i, maxIts, j; // iteration count and maximum number of
                                // iteraterations made

            x0 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            x1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            p1 = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
            maxIts = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

            DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.############");

            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("Polynomail Root Finder By [Gilbert Jimenez]" + "\n");
            System.out.println("Initial Perameters :" + "\n");
            System.out.println("P0 : = " + args[0]);
            System.out.println("p1 : = " + args[1]);
            System.out.println("Tol = " + tol);
            System.out.println("Maximum = " + maxIts + "\n");
            System.out.println("Polynomial is of order:  4 ");

            a = Integer.valueOf(args[4]);
            b = Integer.valueOf(args[5]);
            c = Integer.valueOf(args[6]);
            d = Integer.valueOf(args[7]);

            System.out.println("Terms of polynomial: " + a + "x^3" + "+" + b + "x^2" + "+" + c + "x" + "+" + d);

            {

                // Performing Newton's method

                i = 1;
                error = 100;
                System.out.println("Newtons Method:\t     " + "\n");

                while (i <= maxIts && error > tol)

                {

                    delta = -(f(x0) / fprime(x0));
                    error = Math.abs(delta);
                    xnew = x0 + delta;
                    System.out.println("p" + i + "\t" + fmt.format(xnew));
                    i++;
                    x0 = xnew;

                }

                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("Solution found after " + i + " " + "itterations :" + fmt.format(x0) + "\n");

            }

            {

                // Performing

                j = 1;
                error = 100;
                System.out.println("Secant Method:\t   " + "\n");

                fx0 = f(x0);

                while (j <= maxIts && error > tol)

                {

                    fx1 = f(x1);
                    delta1 = (-fx1 * (x1 - x0) / (fx1 - fx0));
                    error = Math.abs(delta1);
                    xxnew = x1 + delta1;
                    System.out.println("p" + j + "\t" + fmt.format(xxnew));

                    j++;
                    x0 = x1;
                    fx0 = fx1;
                    x1 = xxnew;

                }

                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("Solution found after " + j + " " + "itterations :" + fmt.format(x1) + "\n");

            }

        }

        // function of f

        public static double f(double x)

        {
            return (a * x * x * x + b * x * x + c * x + d);
        }

        // derivative of f

        public static double fprime(double x)

        {
            return (3 * a * x * x + 2 * b * x + c);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are welcome.  Can you kindly mark the answer if you find it useful.  Cheers.